# How to give some data to paypal and take this data back after success?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have paypal subscribe buttons code. I've wrote success and fail urls, when created it all on sandbox paypal site, but anyway after fake payment it goes to index page. Why?

Another question is how to send some data and take the same data back from paypal after payment? I want to send, for example, secret code and detect user by this code after, is it possible? I've tried to add some hidden inputs to the form - it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use paypal IPN  to get back the status of payment along with the customers email and other details which you can use to compare with the customer info on your database or set the return page in paypal dashboard to a script on your server which compares the customer information and updates the database if the purchase is successful.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/